# ¿Cómo interceptar datos vacíos de un marco de datos?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

Tengo un marco de datos con valores que faltan (ni siquiera Nan, simplemente no hay nada). Quiero contar la información que falta.

```
    S02Q18b_01  S02Q18b_02  S02Q18b_05  S02Q18b_06  S02Q18b_07  S02Q18b_08  S02Q18b_09
0                           
1                           
2   -1      0           0   
3   -1                      
4                           
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
4570    -1  -1  1       -1      1
4571    -1  1   1   0   -1  -1  1
4572    -1  1   0   1   -1  -1  1
4573    -1  -1  1   -1  -1  -1  1
4574    0   0   0   0   0   0
```

De hecho `missing = np.where(df[filter_col].applymap(lambda x: x == ''))`, me envía de vuelta:

```
(array([], dtype=int64), array([], dtype=int64))
```

## Actualización

### con `.isnull().sum(min_count=1)`

Intenté tambien:

```
miss_values_count = df[filter_col].isnull().sum(min_count=1)
miss_values_count = miss_values_count[miss_values_count != 0]

print(f"Number of columns with missing values: {miss_values_count.shape[0]}")
if miss_values_count.shape[0]:
    print("Null value count per column: ")
    for name, miss_vals in miss_values_count.items():
        p = miss_vals > 1
        print(f"  - For column name '{name}' there are{'n' if p else ''} "
              f"{miss_vals} ({100*(miss_vals/df[filter_col].size)}) missing values{'s' if p else ''}.")
```

Pero me da `Number of columns with missing values: 0`

### con `fillna.(np.nan)`

Intente [la solucion de Rubiales Alberto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/312189/2633) pero no rellena las valores que faltan:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te dejo una respuesta, si no te funciona por favor házmelo saber :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba a hacer esto, siendo "dataframe" tus datos.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dataframe.fillna(np.nan, inplace=True) #rellenamos todos los valores que faltan con NaN
dataframe.isna().sum() #Sumamos los NaN de cada columna
```

### EDICIÓN 2

Vale viendo tu update, ya sé lo que ocurre, lo que pasa es que esas celdas son un string con espacios o sin nada. Para cambiarlo tienes que hacer lo siguiente:

```
#realizamos las operaciones para cambiar las celdas vacias o con espacios a nan
dataframe = dataframe.replace('\s+', np.nan, regex=True).replace('', np.nan)

#sumamos para saber los números de nan por columnas
dataframe.isna().sum()
```

Lo que hacemos en el **primer replace** es sustituir todos las celdas que tienen un espacio o más por, nan. Y con el **segundo replace** sustituimos todas las celdas que son strings vacios por nan.

Comment: Muchas gracias por su intento. Sin embargo, no llena las celdas vacías :/

Comment: He visto tu actualización a la pregunta y ya sé lo que ocurre, prueba lo que aparece tras edición 2

Comment: Confírmame si te funciono o no? @IggyPass